# Tuning SQL Query for a table with size more than 2GB

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with millions of records and the size of table currently is 2GB and expected to grow further

### Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`column_1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`column_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`column_3` int(11) NOT NULL,
`column_4` int(11) NOT NULL,
`column_5` datetime NOT NULL,
`column_6` time NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`column_1`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_1` (`column_2`,`column_3`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_2` (`column_2`,`column_4`),
KEY `index_3` (`column_3`),
KEY `index_4` (`column_4`),
KEY `index_5` (`column_2`),
KEY `index_6` (`column_5`,`column_2`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`column_3`) REFERENCES `test2`(`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`column_4`) REFERENCES `test2` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fl_3` FOREIGN KEY (`column_2`) REFERENCES `link` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14164023 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I run the following query it is taking around 5-8 secs for different values of column_2. Can some one help to execute this better ?

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM test WHERE test.column_2= 26 and
test.column_5 between '2015-06-01 00:00:00' AND
'2015-06-30 00:00:00'  ;
```

Note: The timings mentioned are captured by executing the query on mysql work bench

Comment: Make `index_6` the opposite way - first column_2, then column_5. Test your query with `EXPLAIN`, it will show you which index it uses and how many rows it has to analyze.

Comment: Bingo!!!. Drastic change in the number of row scans. Could you post this in answer so I can mark it and also could you please explain whats the reason behind such a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index_6` currently has `column_5`, then `column_2`, so MySQL first tries to filter based on the `BETWEEN` clause. However MySQL has limitation that after using index in *range* mode, it can't use the 2nd part of the index (more info in this [blog post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/)).

The correct way of optimizing such queries is to have the *equation* column as 1st part of index and the *range* column as second. Then MySQL will choose rows which have `column_2` value of `26` and then will use 2nd part of index to further filter them based on `column_5` date range.

So the solution is to have an index:

```
KEY `ind_c2_c5` (`column_2`,`column_5`)
```

BTW it is better to give indexes descriptive names, so you know on first sight what they are for...